# how to check weither aspnet profile variable is set OR not?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-profiles

I am using asnet membership.
There is a role named member. In root there is a site-visitor page, on that page in page load I want to check whether member is logged-In or not i.e. profile variable has set OR not.
How can I check that?

I gave search on google as well but failed to get correct answer.

i am setting profile like -

```
 HttpContext.Current.Profile.SetPropertyValue("UserName", UserName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the logged user as you indicate ***I want to check whether member is logged-In or no***

You can use [HttpContext.User Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx)

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User 

if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

Comment: I have tried this... getting NULL in "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User" :(